# Background services not running in MIUI version 10.3.7

Tags: android, background-service, xiaomi, miui

In Xiaomi PocoPhone f1 with MIUI version 10.3.7, the background services are not running when the application is in appkill state. Can anyone help me with this problem??

I have used the permission of the application autostart and removed the battery restriction in my application.

Comment: *Can anyone help me with this problem?* use a different phone

Answer (score 0):

I'm on MIUI 11.1 (eu) and Android 10.
Good chance that MIUI 10 will have these aswell.

There are 2 distinct "Battery Saving" settings/options.

1. Settings -> Passwords & security -> Privacy -> Special app access -> Battery Optimization. Or search for Battery Optimization once in Settings app.
2. Settings -> Battery & performance -> Settings button top right of the screen -> App battery saver.

Or you can flash an AOSP from from xda.

Also checkout https://dontkillmyapp.com/xiaomi